# Error : Build Project through error on Telerik Web UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

Actually i was trying to build MVC project on Visual Studio 2019 but when i'm switching to visual studio 2019 so i get some reference error so finally i resolve all the issues then build solution so i have one error on Telerik.Web.UI reference. I'm already spend 2 hours on this issue but still i don't have an idea about it please help.

```
'Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2015.1.225.45, 
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not 
 supported
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am glad you've managed to solve the problem. 
For anyone else who is experiencing this issue in the future, let he/she checks the following KB article: https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/details/how-to-fix-license-file-related-errors

Answer (score 1):

Solved, problem is that i have telerik license file so delete this license file and add reference then build project, its working.